# How do navigation inside function in Context Provider React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to use Context Api and handle navigation inside a function. 
I have:

**SignupContext.js:**

```
export const SignupProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const signup = async (username, email) => {
         const response = await api.post('/signup', {name, email});
         // How here do navigation.navigate('Main') ?
    }
}
```

**SignupScreen.js:**

```
<Button 
    title="Sign Up" 
    onSubmit={()=>signup(name, email)} 
/>
```

How did i that with class component:

```
async signup() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation; // <- Here set navigation prop
    // ... fetch data ... 
    navigate('Main') // <- Works good
}
```

In functional component usually it looks like:

```
const func = ({ navigation }) => {
    navigation.navigate('Main')
}
```

How do it with Context Provider in **SignupContext.js**?

Comment: Please follow this instruction https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Valid solution:**

1. Create a file navRef.js

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let navigator;

export const setNavigator = (nav) => {
   navigator = nav;
};

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
   navigator.dispatch(
       NavigationActions.navigate({
           routeName,
           params
       })
   );
};
```

2. Import file and add navigaion

```
import { navigate } from '../navRef'; // <- import file

export const SignupProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const signup = async (username, email) => {
         const response = await api.post('/signup', {name, email});
         navigate('Main') // <- navigation to Main screen
    }
}
```